# convert list of list into rows and columns in R

Tags: r

I have a list of list withe the following structure:

```
doc     List of 3
 _id: chr "5b6.."
 firstname: chr "Jhon"
 lastname: chr "Smith"
 age: int 32 
 objectsbought: List of 3 
 ..$ Object1: List of 3
 .. ..$class: int 3
 .. ..$price: int 220 
 .. ..$date: chr "20180312"
 ..$ Object2: List of 3 
 .. ..$class: int 1 
 .. ..$price: int 90
 .. ..$date: chr "20180409"
 ..$ Object3: List of 3
 .. ..$class: int 2
 .. ..$price: int 315 
 .. ..$date: chr "20180623"
```

And I want to convert into a Dataframe with the following structure:

```
_id      firstname  lastname   age   object    class  price  date
"5b6.."  "Jhon"     "Smith"    32    Object1   3      220    "20180312"
"5b6.."  "Jhon"     "Smith"    32    Object2   1      90     "20180409"
"5b6.."  "Jhon"     "Smith"    32    Object3   2      315    "20180623"
```

Please any idea. Thanks.

Comment: Hi David, Can you execute the expression `dput(doc)`  so we can reproduce your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert Any list to Data frame using below code . Welcome to Stack OVerflow

```
final <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, yourlist)
```

Comment: Thanks Hunaidkhan, your solution woks if apply only for objectsbought sub-list, but if I apply to the total of the list  (final <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, doc)). I have the following error: Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :  row names supplied are of the wrong length

Comment: can you provide me reproducible example?